# Is there difference in network latency by choosing different instance classes in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I believe it's not mentioned anywhere by Google. May be some personal practical observation?

Comment: Clarify your question - latency to what - the public Internet, another Google Cloud service, another App Engine instance? Instance size does not affect network latency by itself. Network distance to other services might be effected depending on which rack of servers your application runs on.

Comment: "Instance size does not affect network latency by itself." That's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations):

> App Engine is regional, which means the infrastructure that runs your apps is located in a specific region, and Google manages it so that it is available redundantly across all of the zones within that region.

> Meeting your latency, availability, or durability requirements are primary factors for selecting the region where your apps are run. You can generally select the region nearest to your app's users, but you should consider the locations where App Engine is available as well as the locations of the other Google Cloud products and services that your app uses. Using services across multiple locations can affect your app's latency as well as its pricing.

Additionally, actual latency observed in practice will depend on your application, where your resources are deployed and which GCP services you consume.

Tools such as [Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace/) can help you profile your App Engine applications for latency.